# как выходить из вложенных циклов во внешний в питоне?

Tags: python, циклы, while

Есть некоторый код в логике которого подразумевается наличие нескольких вложенных циклов while
например хочу так:
'''

```
while True:
    if какоето условие:
        while True:
            if ещё условие:
                if какоето условие:
                    while True:
                        if ещё условие:
                            что-то там
                        elif ещё условие:
                            выйти во внешний цикл
                        else:
                            выйти в предыдущий цикл
                else:
                    выйти во внешний цикл
    else:
        if какоето условие:
            while True:
            if ещё условие:
                что-то там
            else:
                выйти во внешний цикл
    time.sleep(5)
```

'''
как это всё сделать?

Comment: это делается с помощью `break`

Comment: break при использовании с while всегда выкинет в начало текущего цикла а нужен выход из него во внешний цикл while

Comment: @OnlineFilm's Да нет, `break` именно прерывает текущий цикл. Если вам нужно выйти ещё выше, то можно выставить какой-то флаг и проверять его там выше.

Answer (score 0):

вообщем нашёл ответ - для меня сработало встроеные бесконечные циклы while во внешнем бесконечном for?